# preg_split returns a non expected number

Tags: php, preg-split

my first question, so please be patient with me...

I have this string:

> "Create a script which will take a string and analyse it to produce
> the following stats. Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet kevin
> buffalo frankfurter, sausage jerky pork belly bacon. Doner sausage
> alcatra short loin, drumstick ham tenderloin shank bresaola porchetta
> meatball jowl ribeye ground round. Ribeye pork loin filet mignon,
> biltong shoulder short ribs tongue ball tip drumstick ground round
> rump pork chop. Kielbasa bacon strip steak andouille ham short ribs
> short loin venison frankfurter spare ribs doner corned beef."

I used this function:

```
$sentenceArray = preg_split('/[.]+/', $string);

foreach ($sentenceArray as $sentence) {
    $numberOfWords = str_word_count($sentence);
    echo '<br>' . $numberOfWords . '<br>';
}
```

and I get this:

```
16

14

16

18

17

0
```

I am expecting 16, 14, 16, 18, 17 but I don't understand where the 0 is coming from?!
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your input string ends with a point, and `preg_split` will split at that point too, generating the string that follows it as a split off, which is the empty string.

Use `preg_match_all` instead. This function will give the result array as an argument, not as return value, and that array will be wrapped. So do:

```
preg_match_all('/[^.]+/', $string, $sentenceArray);
foreach ($sentenceArray[0] as $sentence) {
    $numberOfWords = str_word_count($sentence);
    echo '<br>' . $numberOfWords . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`preg_split()` is splitting on the full stops, including the very last one, which results in an empty string being returned in the array.

There is a flag you can use to remove empty elements

```
$sentenceArray = preg_split('/[.]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php for more details

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to exclude the last string that include nothing thats why it was returning 0 words in it. You can use the following code.

```
<?php
$string = "Create a script which will take a string and analyse it to produce the following stats. Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet kevin buffalo frankfurter, sausage jerky pork belly bacon. Doner sausage alcatra short loin, drumstick ham tenderloin shank bresaola porchetta meatball jowl ribeye ground round. Ribeye pork loin filet mignon, biltong shoulder short ribs tongue ball tip drumstick ground round rump pork chop. Kielbasa bacon strip steak andouille ham short ribs short loin venison frankfurter spare ribs doner corned beef.";
$sentenceArray = explode(".", $string);
foreach ($sentenceArray as $sentence)
{
    if ($sentence != "")
    {
        $numberOfWords = str_word_count($sentence);
        echo '<br>' . trim($numberOfWords) . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last DOT from that sentence.